# Spring WebFlux Security - SecurityWebFilterChain returning 401 for permitAll endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm hoping to expose some endpoints for public access, such as "/docs", "/v3/api-docs", etc.
Currently when visiting the endpoint it returns a 401.

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http {
            csrf { disable() }
            authorizeExchange {
                authorize("/actuator/health/**", permitAll)
                authorize("/docs", permitAll)
                authorize("/webjars/swagger-ui/**", permitAll)
                authorize("/v3/api-docs", permitAll)
                authorize("/v3/api-docs/**", permitAll)

                authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
            }
            oauth2ResourceServer { jwt { } }
        }

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle` file for reference:

```
dependencies {
    // AWS and Security
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.18.21')
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:cognitoidentity'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:cognitoidentityprovider'

    // Reactive Kafka
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka'

    // R2DBC Postgres with Pooling
    implementation 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql'

    // Spring Framework
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'

    // Jackson
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'

    // Misc
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.14'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // Test dependencies
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I've tried moving methods around, changing the path, adding a slash, changing dependencies, etc but nothing seems to be working as intended. Has anyone fixed an issue similar to this before? I'm sure it just has something to do with the order that things are being filtered in, if I fix this I'll leave a comment.

Comment: Have you checked that your requests does not contain any Authorization? If an invalid access token is passed, you'll get a 401, even on a public endpoint. Also, you might want to set the security context repository to `NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository`.

Comment: I have double checked this, removed all auth from my request and still face the same issue. Thanks for the comment either way!

Comment: then please enable TRACE level logs for security and add it to your question: 
`logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your post is incomplete or not, but based on what is posted, you need to

- Configure the resource registry handler -- this would explain why even after removing all security related code, you would still have issues.
- I think your jwt configuration is incomplete. I can't really troubleshoot what you have based on what you posted, but I will provide a working example
- I'm fairly certain that the order that the methods are called in building of the security configuration matters. I personally found the ordering of methods to matter.
- You don't need `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` for what you described you're trying to do. (Not saying you don't need it, just not for what you have described) If you really need that, then you are also going to have to add `MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService()` and/or implement a ReactiveUserDetailsService
- Finally, I would try removing `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity` and get it working without that. Again, you don't need it for what you described you're trying to do. If you really need that functionality, add it. Below is code that works without that annotation. Hopefully it helps you configure your code.

Below is the minimum you would need to turn on authentication for certain paths, and not others. It is older (spring boot 2.6.2), so some of the class names may have changed if you're using spring boot 3

Configuration for CORS and registering the resource handler

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.springframework.http.CacheControl
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.CorsRegistry
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistry
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class CorsConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .maxAge(3600)
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .exposedHeaders("*")
    }

    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
    }
}
```

Security Configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerAuthenticationConverter
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.GET
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.router
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse


@Configuration
class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    fun springWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity,
        jwtAuthenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager,
        jwtAuthenticationConverter: ServerAuthenticationConverter) : SecurityWebFilterChain {
        
        val authenticationWebFilter = AuthenticationWebFilter(jwtAuthenticationManager)
        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)

        return http
            .redirectToHttps()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .httpBasic()
                .disable()
            .formLogin()
                .disable()
            .logout()
                .disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/docs/**")         // let the frontend see the documentation without authenticating
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/")                // allow access to the "public" webpage
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/join")            // allow invitation OS detection and redirection without authorization
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/api/users/login") // let the frontend send creds in order to do authentication
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")  // let the frontend preflight requests succeed without authentication
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(("/version"))
                .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun indexRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/index.html") indexHtml: Resource ): RouterFunction<ServerResponse>  =
        router {
            GET("/") { 
                ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(indexHtml)
            }
        }
    
    @Bean
    fun docIndexRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/docs/index.html") docIndexHtml: Resource ): RouterFunction<ServerResponse>  =
        router {
            GET("/docs") { 
                ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(docIndexHtml)
            }
        }
    
}
```

If you would like an example that does use @EnableWebFluxSecurity and may look closer to what you were going for, you should follow this in it's entirety:  https://ard333.medium.com/authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-on-spring-webflux-29b81f813e78  It will look very similar to the code I posted though.